# supremum of $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$ on $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0, y>0 : x+y=2n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Question is to find :

supremum of $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$ on $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0, y>0 : x+y=2n\}$

Options for this are :

- $3n^6$
- $2n^6$
- $4n^6$
- $n^6$

by choosing $x=y=n$ I could see that $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)=n^4(2n^2)=2n^6$

So, supremum can not be $n^6$. So, i can neglect option $n^6$.

I could not think of a better choice to find supremum.

I tried considering $\frac{df}{dx}=0$ and $\frac{df}{dy}=0$ considering $f(x,y)=x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$ but that is not helping much as i need to be take care of the condition $x+y=2n$ also...

I tried taking conditional extremum but it is also not giving much.

$\phi (x,y,\lambda)=x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)+\lambda(x+y-2n)$

we have $\frac{d\phi (x,y,\lambda)}{dx}=0,\frac{d\phi (x,y,\lambda)}{dy}=0$ with condition $x+y=2n$

this is also giving nothing.

I would be thankful if some one can suggest me a way to clear this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if $f(x,y) = x^2 y^2 (x^2+y^2)$, then since $f(0,y) = f(x,0) = 0$, the problem can be written as $\max \{ f(x,y) | x\ge 0, y \ge 0, x+y = 2n \}$. Since
the constraint set is compact, there is a maximum (and the maximum does not occur at either $x=0$ or $y=0$).

It is easy to see that the problem is equivalent to $\max [( f(x,2n-x) | x \ge 0, x \le 2n \}$.

Letting $\phi(x) = f(x,2n-x)$, we get $\phi'(x) = 4x (x-2n) (x-n) \left( 3\,{x}^{2}-6\,n\,x+4\,{n}^{2}\right)$.

Since $\phi(0) = \phi(2n) = 0$, we can ignore those. Since $3\,{x}^{2}-6\,n\,x+4\,{n}^{2}$ has no real roots, this just leaves $x=n$. Hence the maximizer is $(n,n)$, and the value is $f(n,n) = 2 n^6$.

Comment: I am sure you mean max when you write min in second line...

Comment: Thanks! Hard to change old habits...

Comment: I really like your way of reducing the problem to much smaller case... Thank you so much... This is so clear... :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you not supposed to *solve* the mathematical question itself rather than try to guess the correct answer by elimination and using the knowledge that all are wrong except one? In the present case, $x=nu$ and $y=n(2-u)$ for some $u$ in $(0,2)$ and the goal is to maximize $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)=n^6a(u)$ with $$a(u)=u^2(2-u)^2(u^2+(2-u)^2),
$$
thus it suffices to compute the maximal value of $a$ on $(0,1)$. The logarithmic derivative of $a$ is
$$
\frac{a'(u)}{a(u)}=\frac2u-\frac2{2-u}+\frac{2u-2(2-u)}{u^2+(2-u)^2}=4(1-u)\left(\frac1{u(2-u)}-\frac1{u^2+(2-u)^2}\right).
$$ 
The parenthesis is always positive hence $a'(u)$ has the sign of $1-u$. In particular, $a(u)$ is maximal at $u=1$ and $a(1)=2$ hence the maximum of $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$ on $S$ is $2n^6$.

Comment: I am sorry for my intention of cancelling out false statements... I was not having enough machinery so i thought i may some find pattern in trying to eliminate the cases but i could not find it...

Comment: Alternatively, the method of conditional extrema works like a charm.

Comment: Cancelling out false statements has the huge disadvantage that one leaves the exercise having learned nothing.

Comment: I totally agree with your intention...

Comment: I learn a lot from this answer: divide $n$ to slightly simplify the problem; take logarithm derivative of $a$ instead of take derivative of $a$ (this method may help me a lot in the future, I think). Thanks!

Comment: @DuPhan You are welcome (good summary of the approach, by the way).